# How to pass a variable from a.phtml Block to its parent block?

Tags: template, custom-block

I've created a child block and inside there is a counter.
Now I need that value from the counter but the output is/shall before my block.

Is that possible?

It shall look like this:

```
html
 output the value of my counter
 childBlock (inside that block I will retrieve my counter value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get childblock and pass parameters to it.

So in the parent before the `getChildHtml('childBlock')` function use `echo $this->getChild('childBlock')->setCounter(123)->toHtml();`

Answer (score 1):

The child block is not rendered before `getChildHtml()` is called. So if you calculate this counter during rendering (i.e. in the template) you need to render it before you actually echo the result:

```
$_childHtml = $this->getChildHtml('child_alias');
echo $this->getChild('child_alias') - >getData('counter');
echo $_childHtml;
```

In the child block you have to save the counter variable like this:

```
$this->setData('counter',  $value) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two possibilities:

1. In the parent block, you can store the value in the session with e.g.:

   ```
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCounter('counterValue');
   ```

   And then retrieve the value in your child block with e.g.:

   ```
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCounter();
   ```
2. In the parent block, you can store the value in the registry with e.g.:

   ```
   Mage::register('counter', 'counterValue');
   ```

   And then retrieve the value in your child block with e.g.:

   ```
   Mage::registry('counter');
   ```